# Method isn't working in Fragment (But works in Activity)

Tags: android

I am creating an app using fragments.  I have code that works in an activity, but the same code doesn't work in a fragment.  Here is my code:

```
package com.example.currencyconverter;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    ProgressDialog progressBar;
    EditText edittextdollars;
    EditText edittexteuros;
    TextView dollars;
    TextView euros;
    RadioButton dtoe;
    RadioButton etod;
    RadioGroup radiogroup;
    Spinner spinner1;
    Spinner spinner2;
    Button calculate;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        calculate = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        edittextdollars = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edittextdollars);
        edittexteuros = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edittexteuros);
    }

    public interface CurrencyConverter {
        public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws Exception;
    }

    public class YahooCurrencyConverter implements CurrencyConverter {
        public double convert(String currencyFrom, String currencyTo) throws IOException {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + currencyFrom + currencyTo + "=X&f=l1&e=.csv");
            ResponseHandler < String > responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler);
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            return Double.parseDouble(responseBody);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();


        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("USD", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("EUR", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("USD", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertEurostoEuros();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            OppositeOfConvertEurostoEuros();
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            OppositeOfConvertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertEurostoEuros();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            OppositeOfConvertDollarstoDollars();
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("INR", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("USD", "INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("INR", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR", "INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("USD", "INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("INR", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("INR", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("EUR", "INR");
        }



        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("JPY", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("JPY", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("US Dollar - USD") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("USD", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("JPY", "INR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("INR", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("JPY", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && text2.equals("Euro - EUR") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("EUR", "JPY");
        }



        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("USD", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("US Dollar - USD") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY", "USD");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("EUR", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Euro - EUR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY", "EUR");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittextdollars.length() > 0 && edittexteuros.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues("INR", "JPY");
        }
        if (text1.equals("Indian Rupee - INR") && text2.equals("Japanese Yen - JPY") && edittexteuros.length() > 0 && edittextdollars.length() == 0) {
            convertvalues2("JPY", "INR");
        } else {
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public String convertvalues(String convertfrom, String convertto) {
        double current;
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
        try {
            current = ycc.convert(convertfrom, convertto);
            edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val * current));
            return "passed";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            return errors.toString();
        }
    }

    public String convertvalues2(String convertfrom2, String convertto2) {
        double current;
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        YahooCurrencyConverter ycc = new YahooCurrencyConverter();
        try {
            current = ycc.convert(convertfrom2, convertto2);
            edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val * current));
            return "passed";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
            e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
            return errors.toString();
        }

    }

    protected void convertEurostoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val * 1.33));

    }

    protected void convertEurostoEuros() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val * 1));
    }

    protected void convertDollarstoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val * 1));
    }

    protected void OppositeOfConvertEurostoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittextdollars.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittexteuros.setText(df.format(val * 1.33));
    }

    protected void OppositeOfConvertDollarstoEuros() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val * 0.75));
    }

    protected void OppositeOfConvertEurostoEuros() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val * 1));
    }

    protected void OppositeOfConvertDollarstoDollars() {
        double val = Double.parseDouble(edittexteuros.getText().toString());
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
        edittextdollars.setText(df.format(val * 1));
    }
}
```

Here is my xml for just the button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/calculate"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/edittexteuros"
android:text="@string/calculate" 
android:onClick="onClick"/>
```

For extra reference, here is the LogCat of where my app crashed:

```
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick(View) in the activity class com.example.currencyconverter.MainActivity2 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'calculate'
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick [class android.view.View]
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3579)
06-30 01:45:56.807: E/AndroidRuntime(1752):     ... 11 more
```

What am I doing wrong?  What is happening here?   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried creating the `onClick` listener for the button programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I have, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you remove the xml line `android:onClick="onClick` when you did?

Comment: I've actually done this before in an activity, but if I copy and paste it into a fragment, the app crashes if I press the button.

Comment: @icanc If I add the onClickListener programmatically, nothing happens when I click the button.

Comment: If I add the onClickListener programmatically, nothing happens when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are missing some code or what, but the addListenerOnButton() method is never called anywhere. I am going to assume that you were probably calling this inside of your activity's onCreate(). You probably also noticed that you cannot use getView() inside of a fragment's oncCreate() because the root view is not accessible until the inflate is called inside of onCreateView().

I recommend doing the following to fix your issue.

First remove the onClick line from your xml as you won't be needing that anymore since we will be registering the button programmatically.

You can also move all of the work you are doing inside of addListernOnButton() into onCreateView().

```
View rootView;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    calculate = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(this);
    edittextdollars = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittextdollars);
    edittexteuros = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittexteuros);
    return rootView;
}
```